# Visual Studio tools for manual Entity Framework modelling

Tags: visual-studio-2010, orm, entity-framework-4

Is there any tooling or support in Visual Studio 2010 for manually creating Entity Framework models?

I'm finding the designer too restrictive in terms of mapping a reasonable complex conceptual model to an efficient and performant storage model and understand that part of this may be due to not all features being supported by the edmx designer in visual studio but have yet to find any support for working with it manually - if anything the lack of xml view on the edmx makes it harder.

I'm also open to suggestions for other ORMs I can look at to replace Entity Framework for use in ASP.NET MVC projects my main requirement being that it be quick and easy to configure.

Answer (score 0):

You might be a good candidate for Code First Entity Framework, it's in CTP5 currently but worth checking out.

Here's a blog post [from Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/08/announcing-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-release.aspx) introducing EF Code First.

Comment: I've been keeping an eye on that, unfortunately CTPs are out of the question for now. Hopefully that will arrive early on next year and save me from some of this worry.